# Orthonormal basis in group ring necessarily characters?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, convolution

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $C(G,\mathbb{C})$ the group ring on $G$ with multiplication being the convolution $\ast$ and unit $\delta_0$. Let $B \subseteq C(G,\mathbb{C})$ be a $|G|$-element subset of orthogonal idempotents with respect to $\ast$, s.t. $\sum_{b \in B} b =\delta_0 $. Is $B = \widehat{G}$, necessarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $C(G,\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C\times\cdots\times\mathbb C$ as an algebra, so you can translate your question to:

> is a complete set of orthogonal idempotents in $\mathbb C\times\cdots\times\mathbb C$  necesarily the standard basis?

Is it?

Comment: i dont know the algebra structure on $\mathbb{C} \times ... \mathbb{C}$, i would guess it is given by $e_i \cdot e_j =\delta_{ij} e_i$?

Comment: Sure. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: You know that $C(G,\mathbb C)$ has as a basis the characters and that they are orthogonal idempotents with su equal to $1$, so you know that as an algebra $C(G,\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C\times\cdots\times\mathbb C$, by an isomorphism that maps $\hat G$ to the standard basis. This allows you to "transport" your question from one algebra to the other,

Comment: my result is that it is unique up to permutation

Comment: could you please verify this (if it is true)..

Comment: It would be best if you added a proof of that to the question or, even better an answer with the full details.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. As Mariano Suárez-Álvarez pointed out, it suffices to show that the standard basis is the unique set of orthogonal idempotents with sum equal to $1$ in the algebra $\mathbb{C} \times ... \times \mathbb{C}$. Let $f_i:=Xe_i$ be another basis. Then the orthogonal idempotent condition translates to $X_{ki}X_{kj}=\delta_{ij}X_{ki}$, thus the entries of $X$ are either $0$ or $1$. The sum equal to $1$ condition translates to $\sum_k\,X_{ki}=1$, which means there is exactly one $1$-entry in every column. Since $X$ must be invertible, there is exactly one $1$-entry in every row. Hence, the $f_i$'s must be a permutation of the $e_i$'s.